# How can I perform a drop down list based on multiple Vlookup outcomes?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-formula

I have some problem with Excel and I can't figure it out. I have data with companies and their locations. See below a sample of the data.

[image]

In Column E I want to have a drop down list (data validation) which lets me choose the different companies, without showing duplicates, so only lets me choose between Apple, Microsoft and Google.

In Column F I want to create a drop down list (data validation) which lets me choose the different locations of column B. So for example, in F1 it should give the option of Amsterdam, Berlin, London and Madrid. In F2 it should give the options of Paris, Madrid and Cape Town. I tried using Vlookup but this only can give one return and not multiple returns as in this case.

Can someone help me with what to do?

Thank you in advance!

Kind regards

Comment: I highly suggest you should watch both [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7fYlWeMQ6L8) video on a drop-down list for unique values, and it's [follow-up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gu4xJWAIal8) on a dependent drop-down list. Follow these steps and it won't be too hard. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It quite complicated, 
**Requirements:**

- **Brands** must be sorted!!!
- **Use Named Ranges**
- **Create Table** !!! With Name TblBrand
- **Brand DataValidation Dropdown** Must be Above City Dropdown as City  Named Range is use City Dropdown position to find Brand Dropdown

Just change StartRow in Named Ranges to start row of your table

**Named Ranges: CTRL + F3**

- StartRow `=Sheet1!$A$1`
- Brands `=tblBrand[Brand]`
- BrandList `=OFFSET(StartRow;1;2;COUNTA(tblBrand[Unique])-COUNTBLANK(tblBrand[Unique]);1)`
- City `=OFFSET(StartRow;MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN();1;1));Brands;0);1;COUNTIF(Brands;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1;COLUMN();1;1)));1)`

Cells C2 formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(Brands;AGGREGATE(15;6;(ROW(Brands)-ROW($B$2)+1)/(MATCH(Brands;Brands;0)=ROW(Brands)-ROW($B$2)+1);ROWS($A$2:$A2)));"")`

[image]

[Excel File Prepared](https://ufile.io/ze5k9)

Now you can dynamically fill Brands and Cities

Comment: Thank you! Is it also possible to have:
Brand                     City
[dropdown]            [drop down]

So, Brand should remain E1, Microsoft should be on E2. City should be on F2 and Paris should remain F2. Is this also possible? 

Thanks!